# How to fix "'gl' is possibly 'null'." using webGL shader in react website

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, webgl, production

The shader works fine in development, but when trying to go to production, it of course errors with
Code being used in app.tsx, run with NextJS, React and TS. Although i'm not the brightest in the shed, I couldn't find something for my specific  issue even when searching just for a type error when something is null, and no, AI also didn't seem to help out either.
`"Type error: 'gl' is possibly 'null'."`

I've already tried using a non-null assertion, but then I'm stuck with

```
14:5  Error: Unexpected console statement.  no-console
81:7  Error: Unexpected console statement.  no-console
93:7  Error: Unexpected console statement.  no-console
```

````
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { mat4 } from 'gl-matrix';


const WebGLComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current!;
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

    if (!gl) {
      console.error('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.');
      return;
    }

    // Vertex shader code
    const vsSource = `
      attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
      attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
      
      uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
      uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

      varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

      void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
      }
    `;

    // Fragment shader code
    const fsSource = `
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
    #endif
    
    #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
    
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    uniform float time;
    
    mat2 m(float a) {
        float c=cos(a), s=sin(a);
        return mat2(c,-s,s,c);
    }
    
    float map(vec3 p) {
        p.xz *= m(time * 0.4);p.xy*= m(time * 0.1);
        vec3 q = p * 2.0 + time;
        return length(p+vec3(sin(time * 0.7))) * log(length(p) + 1.0) + sin(q.x + sin(q.z + sin(q.y))) * 0.5 - 1.0;
    }
    
    void main() {
        vec2 a = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.y - vec2(1.2, 0.5);
        vec3 cl = vec3(0);
        float d = 2.5;
    
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            vec3 p = vec3(0, 0, 4.0) + normalize(vec3(a, -1.0)) * d;
            float rz = map(p);
            float f =  clamp((rz - map(p + 0.1)) * 0.5, -0.5, 1.0);
            vec3 l = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.2) + vec3(4.0, 2.5, 5.0) * f;
            cl = cl * l + smoothstep(2.5, 0.0, rz) * 0.3 * l;
            d += min(rz, 1.0);
        }
    
        gl_FragColor = vec4(cl, 1.0);
    }
    `;

    // Compile shaders and create shader program
    function compileShader(source: string, type: number): WebGLShader {
      const shader = gl.createShader(type)!;
      gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
      gl.compileShader(shader);

      if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        console.error('Shader compilation error: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        gl.deleteShader(shader);
        throw new Error('Failed to compile shader.');
      }

      return shader;
    }

    const vertexShader = compileShader(vsSource, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    const fragmentShader = compileShader(fsSource, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram()!;
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      console.error('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
      return;
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Set up shader attributes and uniforms
    const timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'time');
    const resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'resolution');

    let startTime = Date.now();

    // Set up geometry buffers
    const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer()!;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    const positions = [
      -1.0, -1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,
       1.0,  1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const positionAttrib = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition');
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);

    // Set up matrices
    const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
    const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    const modelViewUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uModelViewMatrix');
    const projectionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uProjectionMatrix');

    function render() {
      const currentTime = (Date.now() - startTime) * 0.001; // Convert to seconds
      gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, currentTime);
      
      const resolution = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
      gl.uniform2fv(resolutionLocation, resolution);

      // Set up model-view and projection matrices
      mat4.identity(modelViewMatrix);
      mat4.ortho(projectionMatrix, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewUniformLocation, false, modelViewMatrix);
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniformLocation, false, projectionMatrix);

      // Clear the canvas
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      // Draw the geometry
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

      // Request the next frame
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    render();

  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="webgl-canvas" />;
};

export default WebGLComponent;```
````